# SLD doesn't display SVG image on certain PostGIS layers

Tags: geoserver, sld, svg

I use a simple sample of SLD, that displays "test.svg" image via GeoServer (2.24.1) for point layers:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>redflag</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>burg</Name>
      <Title>A small red flag</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample of how to use an SVG based symbolizer</Abstract>

      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Red flag</Title>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="test.svg" />
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And I have the issue with some layers, where **gray square is displayed instead of "test.svg" image**. All used layers are PostGIS tables with point (not multipoint) geometry, same SRID, same PostGIS database. And on some layers SLD displays SVG image on other just gray square instead of SVG image.

What could be the reason for such behaviour of some layers?

Comment: are you accessing some of them (the failing ones) via a virtual OWS endpoint - please add the actual URLs for us

Comment: Odd that it's only some layers that have the issue, what's the difference between layers where the svg works and others where it doesn't.  What if you give a full  http URL to the SVG rather than a relative one

Comment: After hours of trying different approaches I just change workspace of particular layer to another workspace and back to original and "test.svg" is displayed normally. I have to repeat this for all my layers (more than 50). It seems this is a bug inside GeoServer.